# how to place dropdown div above other div with scrollable property using css?

Tags: html, css, position

I have bellow sample list with my dropdown menu. My dropdown menu is not coming above "Speed Dialing" box. I want to show this dropdown popup above the controls. How to do this ?

**sample code from html as follows :-**

```
<div class="tree-container">
<div class="trees" style="overflow-y: scroll">
<ul class="tree" id="0" style="display: block;">
<li class="contact">
<div class="text">Digambar Patil</div>
<a class="arrow-submenu">
<img src="img/black_arrow_down.png">
<div class="contact-actions-menu" style="display: none;">
<ul>
<li><span>Call</span></li>
<li><span>Schedule</span></li>
<li><span>View Profile</span></li>
<li class="line"></li>
<li><span>Copy to group</span></li>
<li><span>Move to group</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**css used is as follows-**

```
.tree-container {
background-color: #FCFCFC;
margin-left: 5px;
width: 221px;
padding-bottom: 6px;
margin-top: 5px;
min-height: 277px;
max-height: 470px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.tree-container .trees {
height: 239px;
}
.tree-container .trees .tree li.contact {
margin-top: 4px;
margin-bottom: 4px;
margin-right: 9px;
margin-left: 9px;
padding: 3px 0px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: background-color 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s;
-moz-transition: background-color 0.5s;
-ms-transition: background-color 0.5s;
-o-transition: background-color 0.5s;
}
.tree-container .trees .tree li.contact .text {
margin-top: 2px;
float: left;
font-family: "OpenSansRegular";
font-size: 13px;
color: #797979;
text-decoration: none;
font-smooth: always;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
}
.tree-container .trees .tree li.contact .arrow-submenu {
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
line-height: 18px;
border: 1px solid transparent;
padding: 0px 4px;
float: right;
margin-right: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
display: none;
position: relative;
}
.tree-container .trees .tree li.contact .arrow-submenu .contact-actions-menu {
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid #c8c8c8;
background-color: #FFF;
padding: 7px 7px;
width: 170px;
margin-left: -170px;
margin-top: -2px;
display: none;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make JSFIDDLE ?

Comment: you will have to use `z-index` property for that.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the effect on hover over a name in the list? Something [like this](http://jsbin.com/iXuXiXIm/1/edit)?

Comment: @D.Alexander : yes. Actually i done the functionality by using backbone.js